# What is the derivate of $\arcsin \frac{2x}{1+x^2}$?

Tags: derivatives

I searched on the internet, I even did it myself. I get it is $\frac{-2}{x^2+1} $but on the internet it says it is the positive value of this.

Comment: Without any computations, if $f(x)=\arcsin({2x\over 1+x^2})$ then $f(x)<0$ for small $x<0$ and $f(x)>0$ for small $x>0$. Hence $f'(0)\geq 0$, so the answer $f'(x)={-2\over x^2+1}$ cannot be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Therefore, using the chain rule we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)&=\left.\left(\frac{d}{dy}\arcsin(y)\right)\right|_{y=2x/(1+x^2)}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)\\\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)^2}}\right)\left(\frac{2(1+x^2)-4x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2}{(1+x^2)}\frac{(1-x^2)}{|1-x^2|}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)=\begin{cases}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}&,|x|\le 1\\\\-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}&,|x|>1\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Under the root you have $x^4-2x^2+1=(x^2-1)^2$ and you get the negative one.